# Tomcat 9.0.50 and log4j2 issue

Tags: java, log4j2, tomcat9

I have upgraded from log4j1.2 to to log4j2.17. After upgrading 3 jar files (log4j-core-2.17.1.jar, log4j-api-2.17.1.jar, log4j-1.2-api-2.17.1.jar) app is working fine.
Now when I want to remove the bridge ('log4j-1.2-api-2.17.1.jar') between log4j1.2 and log4j2.17.
When I remove this jar file, I get an error on server start-up. Does tomcat9 support log4j2 only with the bridge ?

```
SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Error deploying deployment descriptor [D:\Project\tomcat\conf\Catalina\localhost\project.xml]
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error starting child
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:731)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:700)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:696)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:690)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1889)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptors(HostConfig.java:583)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:473)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1618)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:319)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:423)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:366)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:948)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:835)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1388)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:921)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:263)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:437)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:934)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:772)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:345)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:476)
    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/compass]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:440)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:728)
        ... 37 more
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lorg/apache/log4j/Logger;
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:3061)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:2248)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.Introspection.getDeclaredFields(Introspection.java:104)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadFieldsAnnotation(WebAnnotationSet.java:269)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationServletAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:137)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:69)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.applicationAnnotationsConfig(ContextConfig.java:332)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:989)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:303)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5135)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        ... 38 more
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.log4j.Logger
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1407)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1215)
        ... 51 more
```

Comment: If you use `org.apache.log4j.Logger` in your code, you need to bundle the class in your web application. There is nothing Log4j-specific in this behavior. If you don't want to use `log4j-1.2-api.jar` nor `log4j.jar`, use Log4j2 directly through `org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger`.

Comment: I have already upgraded my code from log4j1.2 to log4j2, so in my code 'org.apache.log4j.Logger' is already replaced with 'org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger' and there is no issue at compile time. I have also removed 'log4j-1.2-api.jar' jar file. As a part of migration from log4j1 to log4j2, I had added the bridge jar file as mentioned here (https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/migration.html). And now I want to remove this bridge jar file and have my application working only with log4j2 jar files.

Comment: But when I remove the jar file, tomcat does not deploy my application and throws above error message in catalina logs. It looks like it is still trying to refer log4j1 class from somewhere. Please help me fix this issue.

Comment: Even if you don't use `org.apache.log4j.Logger` directly, one of your libraries does. Tomcat fails to scan one of the classes available on the application classpath (probably annotated with `@WebServlet`).

Comment: yes, that's what I thought. How can I find out which third party jar file is causing this issue coz as per exception stacktrace given above, the error is in 'org.apache.catalina' package which is not from the libraries which I am using but could be from tomcat/lib folder. So I thought does tomcat9 always need 'Log4j 1.x bridge' to support log4j2 or I am missing something here.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem occurs during the Servlet 3.0 annotation scanning phase of your application's startup:

- first Tomcat scans your application's classpath for classes annotated with [`@WebServlet`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/servlet/4.0/apidocs/javax/servlet/annotation/webservlet) and other similar annotations,
- then Tomcat uses reflection to inject fields into the previously discovered classes. Reflection actually loads and validates all those classes and here your application fails.

Finding out which library is responsible for this is not easy: look for libraries containing servlets or a `META-INF/web-fragment.xml` file.

You can mitigate the problem by adding `metadata-complete="true"` to your `web.xml` descriptor:

```xml
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
                      http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd"
  version="4.0"
  metadata-complete="true">
    ...
</web-app>
```